# FileNotFoundException Using AES Encryption - Android / Java

Tags: java, android, file, filenotfoundexception, fileoutputstream

I'm attempting encrypt files using AES by converting the files to base64 then applying AES however there is never any output on my SD Card and it appears I'm throwing a FileNotFoundException. I've set a breakpoint at the line:

```
SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Password.getBytes("ASCII"), "AES");
```

however I noticed it is only being reached when I select a folder - but not a file (in either case: there is no encrypted file output).

Also - I'm not sure if this line is correct: `boolean encryptedString = MySecurity.encryptFile(chosenFile);`

I simply need to figure out why I cannot encrypt files using this method.

### Permissions:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
 <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

### LogCat:

```
01-16 19:54:50.551: I/System.out(18108): Sending WAIT chunk
01-16 19:54:50.556: I/dalvikvm(18108): Debugger is active
01-16 19:54:50.751: I/System.out(18108): Debugger has connected
01-16 19:54:50.751: I/System.out(18108): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-16 19:54:50.951: I/System.out(18108): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-16 19:54:51.151: I/System.out(18108): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-16 19:54:51.351: I/System.out(18108): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-16 19:54:51.551: I/System.out(18108): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-16 19:54:51.751: I/System.out(18108): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-16 19:54:51.956: I/System.out(18108): waiting for debugger to settle...
01-16 19:54:52.156: I/System.out(18108): debugger has settled (1454)
01-16 19:54:52.416: E/SensorManager(18108): thread start
01-16 19:54:52.426: D/SensorManager(18108): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K3DH Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*b-c)b8
01-16 19:54:52.476: D/SensorManager(18108): unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*b-c)b8
01-16 19:54:52.476: D/Sensors(18108): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
01-16 19:54:52.476: I/Sensors(18108): sendDelay --- 200000000
01-16 19:54:52.476: D/SensorManager(18108): JNI - sendDelay
01-16 19:54:52.476: I/SensorManager(18108): Set normal delay = true
01-16 19:54:52.516: D/SensorManager(18108): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K3DH Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*b-c)b8
01-16 19:54:52.546: D/libEGL(18108): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_mali.so
01-16 19:54:52.546: D/libEGL(18108): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_mali.so
01-16 19:54:52.551: D/libEGL(18108): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_mali.so
01-16 19:54:52.556: D/(18108): Device driver API match
01-16 19:54:52.556: D/(18108): Device driver API version: 10
01-16 19:54:52.556: D/(18108): User space API version: 10 
01-16 19:54:52.556: D/(18108): mali: REVISION=Linux-r2p4-02rel0 BUILD_DATE=Thu Oct 25 08:43:05 KST 2012 
01-16 19:54:52.576: D/OpenGLRenderer(18108): Enabling debug mode 0
01-16 19:54:55.901: D/SensorManager(18108): unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*b-c)b8
01-16 19:54:55.901: D/Sensors(18108): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
01-16 19:54:55.901: I/Sensors(18108): sendDelay --- 200000000
01-16 19:54:55.901: D/SensorManager(18108): JNI - sendDelay
01-16 19:54:55.901: I/SensorManager(18108): Set normal delay = true
01-16 19:54:56.806: D/SensorManager(18108): registerListener :: handle = 0  name= K3DH Acceleration Sensor delay= 200000 Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*b-c)b8
01-16 19:54:58.341: D/dalvikvm(18108): GC_CONCURRENT freed 121K, 13% free 9638K/11015K, paused 12ms+12ms, total 37ms
01-16 19:54:58.361: D/DIRECTORY(18108): LOST.DIR
01-16 19:54:58.361: D/DIRECTORY(18108): external_sd
01-16 19:54:58.361: D/DIRECTORY(18108): usbStorage
01-16 19:54:58.361: D/DIRECTORY(18108): DCIM
01-16 19:54:58.361: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Android
01-16 19:54:58.361: D/DIRECTORY(18108): ShareViaWifi
01-16 19:54:58.361: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Attachments
01-16 19:54:58.361: D/DIRECTORY(18108): LazyList
01-16 19:54:58.361: D/FILE(18108): syncast.3gp
01-16 19:54:58.366: D/DIRECTORY(18108): download
01-16 19:54:58.366: D/FILE(18108): test.mp3
01-16 19:54:58.366: D/DIRECTORY(18108): ScreenCapture
01-16 19:54:58.366: D/FILE(18108): mp3.sdp
01-16 19:54:58.366: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Videomaker
01-16 19:54:58.366: D/DIRECTORY(18108): bluetooth
01-16 19:54:58.366: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Notifications
01-16 19:54:58.366: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Music
01-16 19:54:58.366: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Podcasts
01-16 19:54:58.371: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Ringtones
01-16 19:54:58.371: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Alarms
01-16 19:54:58.371: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Pictures
01-16 19:54:58.371: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Movies
01-16 19:54:58.371: D/DIRECTORY(18108): EarthRot
01-16 19:54:58.371: D/DIRECTORY(18108): projectM
01-16 19:54:58.371: D/DIRECTORY(18108): jibbigo
01-16 19:54:58.371: D/FILE(18108): darkknight.mp4
01-16 19:54:58.371: D/FILE(18108): idg-wallpaper-signed.apk
01-16 19:54:58.371: D/FILE(18108): DiskCacheIndex-1154456374.tmp
01-16 19:54:58.376: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Photo Editor
01-16 19:54:58.376: D/DIRECTORY(18108): SC2
01-16 19:54:58.376: D/DIRECTORY(18108): data
01-16 19:54:58.376: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Galaxier
01-16 19:54:58.376: D/DIRECTORY(18108): samsungapps
01-16 19:54:58.376: D/FILE(18108): tmp.jpg
01-16 19:54:58.376: D/FILE(18108): syncasterstream9760825383gp
01-16 19:54:58.376: D/FILE(18108): syncasterstream9075633613gp
01-16 19:54:58.376: D/FILE(18108): syncasterstream14259657453gp
01-16 19:54:58.381: D/FILE(18108): syncasterstream5539679723gp
01-16 19:54:58.381: D/FILE(18108): syncasterstream20634352173gp
01-16 19:54:58.381: D/FILE(18108): syncasterstream-15179503023gp
01-16 19:54:58.381: D/FILE(18108): syncasterstream3522853173gp
01-16 19:54:58.381: D/FILE(18108): syncasterstream-18907628143gp
01-16 19:54:58.381: D/FILE(18108): syncasterstream-14453506253gp
01-16 19:54:58.381: D/FILE(18108): Img1361203892838.jpg
01-16 19:54:58.381: D/FILE(18108): DiskCacheIndex739049279.tmp
01-16 19:54:58.381: D/FILE(18108): DiskCacheIndex-2062736231.tmp
01-16 19:54:58.386: D/FILE(18108): DiskCacheIndex-1094825277.tmp
01-16 19:54:58.386: D/FILE(18108): DiskCacheIndex887219410.tmp
01-16 19:54:58.386: D/FILE(18108): DiskCacheIndex1525162948.tmp
01-16 19:54:58.386: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Playlists
01-16 19:54:58.386: D/FILE(18108): darkknight.mp4.SEMP
01-16 19:54:58.386: D/DIRECTORY(18108): log
01-16 19:54:58.386: D/DIRECTORY(18108): media
01-16 19:54:58.386: D/DIRECTORY(18108): urbanspoon
01-16 19:54:58.386: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Nearby
01-16 19:54:58.386: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Documents
01-16 19:54:58.436: D/AbsListView(18108): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-16 19:54:58.531: W/ResourceType(18108): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c0 (t=7 e=704) in package 0 (error -75)
01-16 19:54:58.546: D/F_PATH(18108): /storage/sdcard0
01-16 19:54:58.611: D/SensorManager(18108): unregisterListener:: Trklfufi 9 budiwrd5mrfo5WirfulblrwuFmfulTrklfufi$KfukwiFmfulTrklfufiRvht@,*b-c)b8
01-16 19:54:58.611: D/Sensors(18108): Remain listener = Sending .. normal delay 200ms
01-16 19:54:58.611: I/Sensors(18108): sendDelay --- 200000000
01-16 19:54:58.611: D/SensorManager(18108): JNI - sendDelay
01-16 19:54:58.611: I/SensorManager(18108): Set normal delay = true
01-16 19:55:00.811: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Camera
01-16 19:55:00.811: D/DIRECTORY(18108): Facebook
01-16 19:55:00.851: D/AbsListView(18108): Get MotionRecognitionManager
01-16 19:55:00.971: W/ResourceType(18108): Failure getting entry for 0x010802c0 (t=7 e=704) in package 0 (error -75)
01-16 19:55:00.986: D/F_PATH(18108): /storage/sdcard0/DCIM
01-16 19:55:07.706: D/F_PATH(18108): DCIM
01-16 19:55:36.996: W/System.err(18108): java.io.FileNotFoundException: /DCIM: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-16 19:55:37.006: W/System.err(18108):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:416)
01-16 19:55:37.011: W/System.err(18108):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
01-16 19:55:37.016: W/System.err(18108):    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:105)
01-16 19:55:37.021: W/System.err(18108):    at com.encrpytion.idg.MySecurity.encryptFile(MySecurity.java:83)
01-16 19:55:37.026: W/System.err(18108):    at com.encrpytion.idg.FileExplore$3.onClick(FileExplore.java:175)
01-16 19:55:37.031: W/System.err(18108):    at com.android.internal.app.AlertController$AlertParams$3.onItemClick(AlertController.java:934)
01-16 19:55:37.036: W/System.err(18108):    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:301)
01-16 19:55:37.041: W/System.err(18108):    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1280)
01-16 19:55:37.046: W/System.err(18108):    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3071)
01-16 19:55:37.051: W/System.err(18108):    at android.widget.AbsListView$1.run(AbsListView.java:3973)
01-16 19:55:37.056: W/System.err(18108):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
01-16 19:55:37.056: W/System.err(18108):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
01-16 19:55:37.056: W/System.err(18108):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
01-16 19:55:37.061: W/System.err(18108):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
01-16 19:55:37.061: W/System.err(18108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
01-16 19:55:37.061: W/System.err(18108):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
01-16 19:55:37.061: W/System.err(18108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
01-16 19:55:37.066: W/System.err(18108):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
01-16 19:55:37.066: W/System.err(18108):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
01-16 19:55:37.066: W/System.err(18108): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
01-16 19:55:37.071: W/System.err(18108):    at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
01-16 19:55:37.071: W/System.err(18108):    at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:110)
01-16 19:55:37.076: W/System.err(18108):    at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:400)
01-16 19:55:37.076: W/System.err(18108):    ... 18 more
```

### mySecurity.java

```
public class MySecurity
{
    private static Cipher ecipher;
    private Cipher dcipher;
    private static String Password = "$emP0sTM@rkT0P$3cu!ty12345678912";
    private static String InitialVector = "OFRna73m*aze01xY";

    // ENCRYPTION ******************************************************
    public String encryptText(String plainText)
    {
        String errorText = "Error";

        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Password.getBytes("ASCII"), "AES");
            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(InitialVector.getBytes("ASCII")));
             // Encode the string into bytes using utf-8
            byte[] utf8 = plainText.getBytes("UTF8");

            // Encrypt
            byte[] enc = ecipher.doFinal(utf8);
             // Encode bytes to base64 to get a string
            return Base64.encodeToString(enc, Base64.DEFAULT);  

        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        }


        return errorText;
    }

    public static boolean encryptFile(String filePath)
    {

        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Password.getBytes("ASCII"), "AES");
            ecipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            ecipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(InitialVector.getBytes("ASCII")));

            //create input stream to read in file that needs to be encrypted
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            //create output stream to write out the encrypted results, append .vault to out encrypted files
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath + ".vault");
            //wrap the output stream
            CipherOutputStream encryptedOutputStream = new CipherOutputStream(outputStream, ecipher);

            // Encrypt the file
            int bytes;
            byte[] data = new byte[8];
            while((bytes = inputStream.read(data)) != -1)
            {
                encryptedOutputStream.write(data, 0, bytes);
            }

            // Flush and close streams.
            encryptedOutputStream.flush();
            encryptedOutputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }

    public String decryptText(String cryptoText)
    {
        String errorText = "Error";

        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Password.getBytes("ASCII"), "AES");
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(InitialVector.getBytes("ASCII")));

        // Decode base64 to get bytes
            byte[] dec = Base64.decode(cryptoText, Base64.DEFAULT);        
         // Decrypt
            byte[] utf8 = dcipher.doFinal(dec);        
         // Decode using utf-8
            return new String(utf8, "UTF8");    

        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            errorText = e.getMessage();
        }  
        return errorText;
    } 

    public boolean decryptFile(String filePath)
    {

        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Password.getBytes("ASCII"), "AES");
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(InitialVector.getBytes("ASCII")));

            //create input stream to read in file that needs to be decrypted
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
            //create output stream to write out the decrypted results, remove .vault to from file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath.replace(".vault", filePath));
            //wrap the output stream
            CipherInputStream encryptedInputStream = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, dcipher);

            //Decrypt the file
            int bytes;
            byte[] data = new byte[8];
            while((bytes = encryptedInputStream.read(data)) != -1)
            {
                outputStream.write(data, 0, bytes);
            }

            // Flush and close streams.
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            encryptedInputStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }
}
```

### FileExplore.java:

```
public class FileExplore extends Activity {

// Stores names of traversed directories
ArrayList<String> str = new ArrayList<String>();

// Check if the first level of the directory structure is the one showing
private Boolean firstLvl = true;

private static final String TAG = "F_PATH";

private Item[] fileList;
private File path = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "");
private String chosenFile;
private static final int DIALOG_LOAD_FILE = 1000;

ListAdapter adapter;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    loadFileList();
    showDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
    Log.d(TAG, path.getAbsolutePath());




}

private void loadFileList() {
    try {
        path.mkdirs();
    } catch (SecurityException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "unable to write on the sd card ");
    }

    // Checks whether path exists
    if (path.exists()) {
        FilenameFilter filter = new FilenameFilter() {
            @Override
            public boolean accept(File dir, String filename) {
                File sel = new File(dir, filename);
                // Filters based on whether the file is hidden or not
                return (sel.isFile() || sel.isDirectory())
                        && !sel.isHidden();

            }
        };

        String[] fList = path.list(filter);
        fileList = new Item[fList.length];
        for (int i = 0; i < fList.length; i++) {
            fileList[i] = new Item(fList[i], R.drawable.file_icon);

            // Convert into file path
            File sel = new File(path, fList[i]);

            // Set drawables
            if (sel.isDirectory()) {
                fileList[i].icon = R.drawable.directory_icon;
                Log.d("DIRECTORY", fileList[i].file);
            } else {
                Log.d("FILE", fileList[i].file);
            }
        }

        if (!firstLvl) {
            Item temp[] = new Item[fileList.length + 1];
            for (int i = 0; i < fileList.length; i++) {
                temp[i + 1] = fileList[i];
            }
            temp[0] = new Item("Up", R.drawable.directory_up);
            fileList = temp;
        }
    } else {
        Log.e(TAG, "path does not exist");
    }

    adapter = new ArrayAdapter<Item>(this,
            android.R.layout.select_dialog_item, android.R.id.text1,
            fileList) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // creates view
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView textView = (TextView) view
                    .findViewById(android.R.id.text1);

            // put the image on the text view
            textView.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(
                    fileList[position].icon, 0, 0, 0);

            // add margin between image and text (support various screen
            // densities)
            int dp5 = (int) (5 * getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density + 0.5f);
            textView.setCompoundDrawablePadding(dp5);

            return view;
        }
    };

}

private class Item {
    public String file;
    public int icon;

    public Item(String file, Integer icon) {
        this.file = file;
        this.icon = icon;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return file;
    }
}

@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id)
{
    Dialog dialog = null;
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new Builder(this);

    if (fileList == null) {
        Log.e(TAG, "No files loaded");
        dialog = builder.create();
        return dialog;
    }

    switch (id) {
    case DIALOG_LOAD_FILE:
        builder.setTitle("Choose your file");
        builder.setAdapter(adapter, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                chosenFile = fileList[which].file;
                File sel = new File(path + "/" + chosenFile);
                if (sel.isDirectory()) {
                    firstLvl = false;

                    // Adds chosen directory to list
                    str.add(chosenFile);
                    fileList = null;
                    path = new File(sel + "");

                    loadFileList();

                    removeDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
                    showDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
                    Log.d(TAG, path.getAbsolutePath());
                    Log.d(TAG,(chosenFile!=null)?chosenFile:"chosenFile is null");
                    boolean encryptedString = mySecurity.encryptFile(chosenFile);

                }

                // Checks if 'up' was clicked
                else if (chosenFile.equalsIgnoreCase("up") && !sel.exists()) {

                    // present directory removed from list
                    String s = str.remove(str.size() - 1);

                    // path modified to exclude present directory
                    path = new File(path.toString().substring(0,
                            path.toString().lastIndexOf(s)));
                    fileList = null;

                    // if there are no more directories in the list, then
                    // its the first level
                    if (str.isEmpty()) {
                        firstLvl = true;
                    }
                    loadFileList();

                    removeDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
                    showDialog(DIALOG_LOAD_FILE);
                    Log.d(TAG, path.getAbsolutePath());
                    Log.d(TAG,(chosenFile!=null)?chosenFile:"chosenFile is null");
                    boolean encryptedString = mySecurity.encryptFile(chosenFile);
                }
                // File picked
                else {
                    // Perform action with file picked
                }

            }
        });
        break;
    }
    dialog = builder.show();
    return dialog;
}
```

}

### Download Link:

http://www.sendspace.com/file/den6ue

Comment: Which line is line 83 of MySecurity?

Comment: FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);

Comment: Are you certain the file exists at that point? What do you see if you log `filePath`?

Comment: I tried selecting a file - the breakpoint I set at SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Password.getBytes("ASCII"), "AES"); is never reached

Comment: Any ideas/suggestions? (it's one of the primary issues I'm having)

Comment: This exception has nothing to do with encryption.

Comment: Should I rename the post?

Answer (score 0):

From documentation of `FileInputStream()` constructor...

> **FileInputStream(File file)**
>
> Creates a FileInputStream by opening a connection to an actual file, the file named by the File object file in the file system.

So, if you want to create an instance of `FileInputStream` then you have to pass a `File` object to `FileInputStream()`. But In the following line, you are passing an file path not a file object...

```
FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(filePath);
```

Another problem is that, your `filePath` isn't correct. It contains only this following path...

```
/DICM
```

Which isn't a proper path and its not an actual file path but its a folder path. The correct path should be as follows...

```
/mnt/sdcard/DICM
```

Now, if you want to solve your problem then you have to follow these...

1. Creating a `File` object using actual file name and path.
2. Creating `FileInputStream` object by passing the `File` object into `FileInputStream()` constructor.

Now, say, your file name is `Text.txt` and then your corrected code snippet will be....

```
public boolean decryptFile(String filePath)
    {

        try {
            SecretKeySpec secretKey = new SecretKeySpec(Password.getBytes("ASCII"), "AES");
            dcipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding");
            dcipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, secretKey, new IvParameterSpec(InitialVector.getBytes("ASCII")));

            //Creating File object to into FileInputStream() constructor
            String fileDirectory = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath() + filePath;
            String actualFilePath = fileDirectory + "/" + "Text.txt";
            File actualFile = new File(actualFilePath);

            //create input stream to read in file that needs to be decrypted
            FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(actualFile);

            //create output stream to write out the decrypted results, remove .vault to from file
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(filePath.replace(".vault", filePath));
            //wrap the output stream
            CipherInputStream encryptedInputStream = new CipherInputStream(inputStream, dcipher);

            //Decrypt the file
            int bytes;
            byte[] data = new byte[8];
            while((bytes = encryptedInputStream.read(data)) != -1)
            {
                outputStream.write(data, 0, bytes);
            }

            // Flush and close streams.
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();
            inputStream.close();
            encryptedInputStream.close();

        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (InvalidAlgorithmParameterException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        }catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return false;
        } 
        return true;
    }
```